# Moment of inertia of a solid sphere; spot the mistake

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia, inertia

What an I doing wrong?:

$I = \int r^2dm$

$M = \rho \frac{4}{3} \pi r³$

$dM = \rho \frac{4}{3} \pi 3r²dr = \rho 4 \pi r²dr$

$I = \rho 4π \int r^4dr = \rho 4π \frac{r^5}{5} = \frac{3Mr^2}{5} = \frac{3}{5} Mr^2$

Instead of factor $\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: *spot the mistake ... What an I doing wrong?* Please be aware that check-my-work are usually considered off-topic on this site. I think the members who answered made an exception for your question because you made a conceptual error rather than a calculational one.

Comment: Yes I'm aware that this isn't really well defined for this sites but i knew my question was a conceptual error and since my question is about the method of calculation I must provide my work thus far. But I'll definitely try to avoid questions like these.

Answer (score 2):

You have not used the correct definition of $I$.

The moment of inertia is defined as
$$I=\int r^2_\perp dm=\int r^2_\perp\rho dV.$$ Using spherical coordinates $$\vec r=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=r\begin{pmatrix}\cos\varphi\sin\theta\\ \sin\varphi\sin\theta\\\cos\theta\end{pmatrix},$$ we get $$r_\perp^2=x^2+y^2=r^2\sin^2\theta\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,dV=r^2\sin\theta drd\varphi d\theta$$ and thus $$I=\rho\int r^2\sin^2\theta dV=\rho\int_0^R r^4dr\int_0^{2\pi} d\varphi\int_0^\pi\sin^3\theta d\theta=\rho\frac{R^5}{5}2\pi\frac{4}{3}=\frac{2}{5}MR^2$$since$$\rho=\frac{M}{4/3\pi R^3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the moment of inertia about an *axis* through the center, and that distance is not always $r$ for a mass element $dm$ *from the axis*.

Comment: Ah of course, how stupid of me, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

While your calculation is correct, your derivation starts from the wrong premise.

A moment of inertia is calculated **about a given axis of rotation**, not about a point.

I assume in your case the axis of rotation runs through the Centre of Mass of the uniform sphere.

In that case, you need to slice up the sphere into *infinitesimal cylinders* (circular plates) along the axis, then sum by integration the moments of inertia of these plates along the axis.

You can find the full [derivation here](https://www.miniphysics.com/uy1-calculation-of-moment-of-inertia-of-solid-sphere.html).